# Spark UI Authentication

Tags: security, authentication, apache-spark

I am trying to find a way to secure my Apache Spark cloud cluster.

From the spark documentation I get the following:

spark.ui.filters - Comma separated list of filter class names to apply to the Spark web ui. The filter should be a standard javax servlet Filter.

How do I get authentication to work with a servlet? Since I do not trust my own implementation, is there a "standard"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by securing your cloud cluster? Restricting access to the monitoring UI through filters is IMO the wrong approach. Why not block access to the ports altogether? Also, the UI will not enable you to manage any kind of job submission control